# not all code paths return an value error for a timer

Tags: c#, timer, asp.net-mvc-5

Orders controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FirstClassCreate(FormCollection values)
{

    var order = new Order();
    TryUpdateModel(order);
    var customer = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name);
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

    try
    {
        //I need to get the order.timeleft to start a count down

        order.timeleft = timer(); 
        //Save Order
        storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
        await storeDB.SaveChangesAsync();
        //Process the order
        cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        order.Total = cart.GetFirstClass();

        order = cart.CreateOrder(order);

        return RedirectToAction("FirstClass", "Checkouts");
    }
    catch
    {
        //Invalid - redisplay with errors
        return View(order);
    }
}
```

I need the timer to decrease by 1 every second and one the time = 0 return timerleft as false, however I am getting problems with the  public ActionResult timer highlighting timer states that '.timer(Order)': not all code paths return a value

```
public ActionResult timer(Order order)
{
    int time;
    order.timeleft = true;
    time = 30;
    do
    {
        if (time > 0)
        {


            time = time - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user ran out of time, stop the timer, set timeleft = false
            var orderToBeChanged = db.Orders
        .Where(o => o.HasPaid == false && o.Email == User.Identity.Name)
              .OrderByDescending((o => o.OrderDate)).First();
            order.timeleft = false;
            db.SaveChanges();


        }
    } while (time > 0);
}
```

Comment: Your `timer` method has a return type of `ActionResult` but never actually returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

In function `public ActionResult timer(Order order)` in any place you dont return any value, and in header you said this function returns type `ActionResult`

In your case you can modify `timer` function in this way:

```
public bool timer(Order order)
{
    ...
    } while (time > 0);

    return order.timeleft;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method of type ActionResult must return an ActionResult, i.e.

```
public ActionResult Timer(Order order)
{
    ...
    return myActionResult;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want it to return anything mark it as void

```
public void Timer(Order order)
{
    ...
}
```